# ViewPager is not showing up on bottomSheetDialog

Tags: android, android-design-library, bottom-sheet

ViewPager is not showing up on BottomSheetDialog. Here is the implementation.

```
public void show(final BoxItem boxItem) {
        bottomSheet = (mContext).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_change_size_and_frequency, null);
        bottomSheetDialog.setContentView(bottomSheet);
        bottomSheetDialog.show();
        hashMap = boxItem.getFrequencyItemConfigHashMap();
        initViews();
        setupViewPagerAndTabs();
    }

    private void setupViewPagerAndTabs() {
        Set<String> keySet = hashMap.keySet();
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(((AppCompatActivity) mContext).getSupportFragmentManager());
        for (String key : keySet) {
            adapter.addFragment(SearchDetailItemsFragment.getInstance(hash.get(key)), key);
        }
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    }

    private void initViews() {
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) bottomSheet.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) bottomSheet.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    }
```

Comment: Can you share your screen what exactly is happening ?

Answer (score 0):

Fragments are not allowed on Dialogs. I solved the problem by using [BottomSheetDialogFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetDialogFragment.html) which allow to do various things to keep the fragment's lifecycle.